# Pop string from left to right if matches in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If you see two consecutive characters that are the same, you pop them from left to right, until you cannot pop any more characters.
Return the resulting string.
let str = "abba"

"abba" - pop the two b's -> "aa"

"aa" - pop the two a's -> ""

return ""

Here's what i have tried so far:

```js
function match(str){
    
 for (let i = 0; i< str.length; i++){
   if (str[i] === str[i+1]){
     return str.replace(str[i], ""); 
   
    } 
  }
};
match('abba');
```

It removes one b only. On first loop, i want it to remove two b's and console the output. On second i want the remaining two a's to remove and console the output. Also It would be great if good time complexity is maintained.

Comment: Do you mean 2+ identical consecutive characters, rather than strictly 2?

Comment: Yes, i meant strictly 2 @jarmod

Answer (score 2):

Use [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#In_computer_science).

```js
function match(str){
    if(str.length==1 || str=="") {
        return str;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i< str.length-1; i++) {
        if(str[i] === str[i+1] && i+2==str.length) {
            return str.substr(0,i);
        } else if(i+2==str.length) {
            return str;
        } else if (str[i] === str[i+1]) {
            return match(str.substr(0,i)+str.substr(i+2,(str.length)-(i+2))); 
        }
    }
};

console.log('aa = '+ match('aa'));
console.log('abba = '+ match('abba'));
console.log('abccba = '+ match('abccba'));
console.log('abdccba = '+ match('abdccba'));
console.log('aabdccba = '+ match('aabdccba'));
console.log('abdccbaa = '+ match('abdccbaa'));
console.log('abbac = '+ match('abbac'));
console.log('abbcc = '+ match('abbcc'));
```

Comment: console.log('abbac = '+ match('abbac')) This thows undefined to your code. @ThilankaD

Comment: Okay, can you please tell me the time and space complexity of this solution? @ThilankaD

Comment: @WedevsMobileapp if this answers your question mark it as an answer or else if you have solved the problem on your own please add your solution here and mark it as the answer so it may help someone else.